# Is there a way for python to access a text file that can’t be access in file explorer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, microsoft-file-explorer

I am making a program that uses text files on a network drive and I don’t want anyone to access the text file from file explorer. I have already hidden the file but I have realised that most people on the network have hidden folders shown.

How would I do this?

Comment: perhaps you're really looking for _encryption_

Comment: Unless encryption also stops people deleting files…

Comment: have your administrator set up the permissions such that users cannot delete the files and consider backing them up to a more secure location (Amazon Glacier et al., having an intern make and check DVDs..)

Comment: File/Folder permissions is your only route if you have to stop people from performing certain activities on a file (like renaming, deleting, etc). Security through obscurity, which you already tried, is a bad idea.

Comment: Should I just give users read permissions then? Or do they need others for python to read and edit the text file? Or is read not the correct one?